# Printing hash of array as values with Dumper leads to infinite recursion

Tags: perl, hash, each

The following code leads to infinite recursion. If printed without **Dumper** then it works as expected. Why **Dumper** causes recursion?

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1 = (
          'key1' => ['val1']
);

while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash1) {
    print Dumper \%hash1;
}
```

Comment: Setting Maxdepth might help. It defaults to 0.

Comment: You are looping through the elements of the hash and then dump the whole hash? What's the idea behind that? Did you want to `print Dumper $value` inside the loop?

Comment: I added `each` to tags as this is an excellent example of its trickery, so that this question is more easily found.  (Even though it wasn't obvious that that was the problem.)

Answer (score 6):

`each` to blame here. You're using it in your loop, and `Data::Dumper` uses it to iterate over the contents of hashes.

From [the documentation of `each`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each) (Emphasis added):

> The iterator used by `each` is attached to the hash or array, and is shared between all iteration operations applied to the same hash or array. Thus all uses of `each` on a single hash or array advance the same iterator location. All uses of `each` are also subject to having the iterator reset by any use of `keys` or `values` on the same hash or array, or by the hash (but not array) being referenced in list context. This makes `each`-based loops quite fragile: it is easy to arrive at such a loop with the iterator already part way through the object, or to accidentally clobber the iterator state during execution of the loop body. It's easy enough to explicitly reset the iterator before starting a loop, but there is no way to insulate the iterator state used by a loop from the iterator state used by anything else that might execute during the loop body. **To avoid these problems, use a `foreach` loop rather than `while`-`each`**.

Like so:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash1 = (
          'key1' => ['val1']
);

foreach my $key (keys %hash1) {
    print Dumper \%hash1;
}
```

Basically, don't use `each` unless you have full control over what's done with the hash in the body of the loop over its results.

The exact cause of an infinite loop is explained with this bit of documentation:

> After `each` has returned all entries from the hash or array, the next call to `each` returns the empty list in list context and `undef` in scalar context; the next call following that one restarts iteration.

The `each` loop in the `Dumper()` code first resets the internal iterator, and then repeats until it returns an empty list; then `each` is called again in the test of your `while` loop and starts afresh with the first (only) element of the hash, and repeats forever.

Comment: You are still printing the entire hash once for each key in the hash. And never using the key.

Comment: @TLP Yeah, I have no idea what OP's end goal with this construct is, so I just rolled with it.